# How do I edit the Adobe Template for PDF Packages?

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop, adobe-acrobat

I frequently bundle multiple .pdfs into packages to maintain the digital signatures. As a result I can either put a document without signatures as the cover, or use the Adobe template. Since it is simpler to use the default settings (i.e. template), and the typical file included in the packages *that doesn't* have a signature is not a good cover sheet, I would like to edit the template to be something other than an Acrobat 8.0 advert.

How do I edit Adobe's PDF Package cover sheet template?

(Running Adobe Acrobat Standard 8.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a work around which is to package an unrelated template file (i.e. that you wish to be the template) with the remainder of the files you we're packaging to begin with. Mark the template file to be the cover sheet, and you have an ad hoc replacement to the Adobe file.

While this is effective at adding a cover sheet and uses the actual 'cover sheet' element, this does not solve the problem of being stuck with the Adobe template as the default cover, it means that you have to package an extra file every time you follow this procedure, and would be a hassle to implement across multiple users.